# E-mailing a paper under review to a prospective PhD advisor; a co-author wants all co-authors to be CC-ed. Is this OK?

Tags: phd, email

So I am stuck in a very weird situation. I am a prospective PhD student, and I emailed a supervisor that works in a field of research very close to mine, and is very successful.
He replied stating that he is interested to have me in his team, and requested my papers. One of my papers is under review.
I asked my co-author which is my advisor for a permission, and she said it is okay to send the papers as long as I cc all co-authors in the email.

I feel like this is not a nice way of emailing a distinguished professor, especially that I do not understand the point of ccing the co-authors. I might offend the professor, which I do not want to happen.

I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 2):

> I asked my co-author which is my advisor for a permission

Here a better move would have been that of asking *all* your coauthors for permission.

I'd now:

1. Inform all your coauthors, cc'ing your advisor, asking if they are OK with that.
2. Inform your advisor that you would not feel comfortable in cc'ing the coauthors in the discussion with the prospective supervisor.
3. Write to the prospective supervisor without further copying your coauthors. At most, if your current advisor insists with that, use a *blind* cc.

Comment: So you are saying to Email my other co-author, and cc my advisor and ask if the other co-author is okay with it? but not cc them in the mail reply to the prospective prof?

Comment: @sandra Yes, I'm suggesting to email all your other coauthors, cc-ing your advisor. If there is just one more coauthor, email them with your advisor in cc. You can also say that you previously discussed this with your advisor.

Comment: @sandra I've made an edit with one more step.

Comment: This feels paranoid to me.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Better feel paranoid than sorry...

Comment: @Massimo why sorry? as a co-author of a scientific paper that it is meant to be published, why sharing it with one confident person (i.e. professor) would need an authorisation from the co-authors when it is under review?

Comment: @sandra Although I find the whole idea of asking for permission strage, I suggest that you send an independent email to the new professor related only to this paper where you can CC all your co-authors and you start it with; "According to the request of Prof. XYZ, ....." The new prof will understand that this additional step isn't coming from u and u sound more professional. So, u satisfy everyone!

Comment: @Younes Because not all authors are comfortable in sharing papers under review and some can get quite angry about that.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano So I am thinking of sending two emails (based on you and Oleg's response). One email at first in reply to the Prof, stating that I am doing this because my advisor wants me to do so (even tho she said to write it in a way like she doesn't know I am CCing her, I really don't know why she's doing this, but I cannot make myself look bad). and then write another reply to the prof's email with the papers and CCs. Would this be better?

Answer (score 2):

A co-authored paper is automatically a piece of *intellectual property collectively owned*, and if there is no explicit arrangement otherwise, it is to be handled by unanimous decisions/consensus. It is not yours to do as you please with it, plain and simple.

Your supervisor *relaxed* this by saying to you that you just have to inform the co-authors while actually sending the paper out. I strongly disagree.

You do have to take your coauthors' *permission/consensus* to send the paper out (and if you don't like that, start writing solo papers).

So the advise already received is sound: communicate with the co-authors, obtain by e-mail their agreement to send the paper out, send the paper out without cc-ing them.

Comment: So if you were the prospective advisor,  would you be offended? The co-authors are cool with it as long as I CC them.

Comment: @sandra I would have found it weird that you are cc-ing anybody while sending me your papers, because I would expect that any kind of permission etc as I have mentioned in my answer would have been obtained prior to e-mailing me your papers. My automatic thought would be to e-mail you back asking you why you are cc-ing other people. And why are your co-authors _want_ to be cc-ed? Now that they know and are ok with the act? This is the weird part. Their name is on the paper, it is not like you are presenting it as your work alone.

Comment: If I were the prospective advisor, I would be suspicious of a prospective student that shared work in progress without the explicit agreement of **all** coauthors (not just the advisor).  Also, it's not my paper, so what right do I have to be offended by its authors' desire to be kept in the loop?

Comment: @JeffE Let's accept the OP's fear and anxiety about "offending in any way imaginable the prospective supervisor", however exaggerated/unfounded it may be.

Comment: This is wrong because the intellectual property is owned by the university, not the authors, in most cases.  This is a question of ethics/culture, not law.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Who said anything about "law"? I certainly didn't. The concept of collective ownership and related notions in the post exist independent of any legal incarnation.

Comment: "Intellectual property" is a strictly legal concept.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Both words are part of the common vocabulary of English, so no, "Intellectual property" means a product of my mind that is mine... in parallel of course with its legal meaning.

Comment: I think you are claiming that intellectual property is a moral right.  That is wrong.  It is only a legal right.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist _This is wrong because the intellectual property is owned by the university, not the authors, in most cases_ — In every university I've ever been part of, university policy explicitly acknowledges that *authors*, both students and faculty, retain all intellectual property rights (or as they are called in this context, copyright) to their *papers*.  So in my experience, even in the strictest legal sense, the first sentence of the answer is correct.  (I am not a lawyer.)

Comment: @JeffE Universities definitely retain patent rights, which are the (potentially) valuable rights.  Are you sure about copyright?

Comment: Patents are not papers.  Yes, I am sure about copyright. Here are [my university's regulations](https://www.bot.uillinois.edu/governance/general_rules); see "Section 4: Copyrights".  Also, many/most journals ask authors to transfer copyright to their papers to the publisher; if authors didn't retain copyright to their papers, they wouldn't be able to legally sign those forms.

Answer (score 0):

I generally agree with [Massimo Ortolano](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/158341/46265), but does it not work out easier?

1. Write the actual email to the important prospective advisor with a response to everything else. Mention that the paper under review will come with a separate email.
2. Write an email to the same advisor, CC'ing all the authors of the paper under review, as requested. This email states:

> Dear Prof. XXXX,
>
> you were interested in my research. Here is my latest work, which is still under review.
>
> I CC all the coauthors. If you have questions on it, you are welcome to ask me, but you might want to address the person who did the contribution you are interested in (per author statement `-- you _have_ author statement, don't you?`).
>
> Nada, nada.

It might come over as a bit of a weird flex, but I would not see it as offensive.

The benefit of my approach is that you do not overthink it. You are slashing your strange case into two very regular approaches: an email to a prospective supervisor and a mail, sharing a paper of yours.

Comment: As discussed in the comments [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/158342/46265), the prospective advisor _should not_ be angry with this approach. But your coauthors of the paper under review _might._ So, that's what for is asking them separately, as suggested by the other answer.

Comment: My advisor insisted that I reply to the email and CC them. That is what I think would cause the problem. I don't know why but she insists that this is the safe way even though the professor is highly respected.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it's fine to CC your coauthors when sharing a draft of your paper.  It just informs your coauthors that someone was interested in your work.

Comment: Have you done this before? Didn't the prof get offended?

Comment: You're not taking into account that the OP communications with the prospective advisor do not have the only goal of sharing a paper, but also to find a position and there can be additional information, discussion etc. that need not to be seen by the coauthors.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Exactly, that is what I am concerned about.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano There is no need to include the additional information in the email, but surely it's not a secret that sandra is a prospective PhD student.

Comment: It can just be "Dear Prof. X, Here is the manuscript you requested."

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist There is certainly the possibility of sending two separate emails, one with the additional information and one with the paper, but the other coauthor may not like anyway to have the paper shared when under review. In my experience, while some authors are quite open, some others really don't like to share their draft papers and can get quite mad about that. Since we don't know the authors involved, as I said, better be safe than sorry. Or do you really want to put the OP at risk?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Damn, saw this comment just after posting my answer, suggesting exactly this.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Ethical scientists do not keep secrets.